# Graph Api invoke-restmethod -filter returns all the results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm running a powershell query

```
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$upn/memberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true&$orderby=displayName&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'Group_name')"

$groupacheck = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($token)"; ConsistencyLevel = "eventual"} -Uri $Url -Method Get)
```

This should find if a user has group membership to a particular group, however it just returns all groups.

What am I missing as it should be possible?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-5-use-filter-and-odata-cast-to-get-groups-with-a-display-name-that-starts-with-a-including-a-count-of-returned-objects

Answer (score 0):

I tried from end in graph explorer its working fine for me, could you please enter your user_id in place of $upn , and Could you please try the below url in graph explorer https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/memberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true&$orderby=displayName&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'group_name'),
if it work then try in PowerShell. [image]

Comment: So I tried Graph explorer and worked fine, powershell it does not though?

Answer (score 0):

Created a doc bug for this issue - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/16422 , you can track the update by following the bug .

Thanks